# Is pulling and pushing the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vibrations

In the following image, you are asked to create an equation that represents the position of the moving part as the magnet pulls the metal object.

[image]

If the force acting on the system is constant and the positive x direction is going towards the direction of spring, I used the following equation to represent the position of x with respect to time:

\begin{align}
F_o &= \ddot{x} + \frac{c}m\dot{x}+\frac{k}mx \\
\frac{N^2i^2\mu_oA}{m4(x+g)^2} &= \ddot{x} + \frac{c}m\dot{x}+\frac{k}mx 
\end{align}

However, am being told that the this equation represents a magnet that is pushing the mass rather than pulling it. I thought that regardless of whether the mass was being pushed or pulled, it would still result in the same equation. My reasoning for this was that even if the mass being pushed, the spring and damper would always act in the opposite direction of the applied force.

If this is not the case, what is the correct way to represent the motion of a mass being pulled by the magnet and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation depends on how you define $x$. According to the expression of the force you have, increasing $x$ increases the gap, so $x$ must be increasing as you go to the right. With this convention, you need to negate the sign of the force applied by the electromagnet for this equation to be correct.

You are right that with $x$ defined to be $0$ at the equilibrium position of the spring, the damping and spring forces have the same form regardless of the direction: $-c\dot x$ and $-k x$, respectively. With $mF_o$ as the force due to the electromagnet (to be consistent with your notation), that gives you

$$\ddot x = -\frac{c}{m}\dot x - \frac{k}{m} x + F_o.$$

The sign convention for $x$ starts to matter from this point on. If you define $x$ to increase as you go to the right, then positive $F_o$ would have the effect of pushing the mass to the right, and vice versa. Since you know the electromagnet will pull the mass to the left, the correct expression is
$$F_o = -\frac{N^2i^2\mu_oA}{m4(g+x)^2}.$$

Now if you define $x$ such that it increases as the mass moves to the left, positive $F_o$ would correspond to the mass being pulled to the left, so the correct expression would be
$$F_o = \frac{N^2i^2\mu_oA}{m4(g-x)^2}.$$

Note the difference in the denominators: positive $x$ increases the gap in the first case but decreases it in the second case.